# If yelling is so good, why MMA fighters don't yell often

Tags: tae-kwon-do, mixed-martial-arts, sparring, breathing, kiai

In our class, the benefits of yelling/shouting, i.e. Kihap, in sparring are sometimes pointed out. If yelling is so beneficial, why MMA fighters don't yell often? Or do they?

Comment: https://forums.sherdog.com/threads/why-no-karate-kiai-in-mma.2231409/

Comment: I suspect an additional factor is that the standard yell you hear in class that people recognize is also more about synchronizing a group movement.

Comment: I definitely see fighters of all strikes kiai. It may not be as stylized as the synchronized yell found in karate/TKD/etc, but it's definitely common to brace and exhale when executing technique.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per [the provided link](https://forums.sherdog.com/threads/why-no-karate-kiai-in-mma.2231409/), there's a number of factors going on.

- First of all, a *kiai* is as much about a forceful exhalation and a focus of purpose as it is actually yelling. Many of the fighters do just that, grunting or exhaling on a heavy strike without actually yelling.
- One of the other purposes of a *kiai* is to startle the opponent. In the Octagon, most fighters are prepared for battle, so to speak, so there are less likely to startle if someone yells.
- There is also the cultural difference that many people get into MMA from boxing, which doesn't tend to do the yelling thing.
- The *kiai* is often done on a single decisive strike, something that a TMA like Karate tends to emphasize whereas MMA tends to focus on multiple successive blows.
- Lastly, the traditional *kiai* in martial arts, especially during forms, is often used as much to synchronize movements (or to indicate such precision) as to actually generate power to attack.

Comment: As a shotokan karate practitioner, I'd like to say we've never used kiai in group katas to synchronise. If you have to use kiai to synchronise, you're not synchronised at all. I also think that the actual movements are better indicator of precision than kiai.